# Feature Layer not showing up when adding an automatic rotation function to SceneView

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am building a simple web application using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (4.x). I created a map with an associated `FeatureLayer` and then a `SceneView` and everything works fine. However, I'm trying to make the scene rotate automatically. When I implement a function using `scheduling` the rotation works but the `FeatureLayer` dissapears and only the basemap is visible. Has anyone experienced the same problem or does someone know an approach to this issue?

Here is my code. The function that makes rotate the scene is at the end, inside `scheduling.addFrameTask`. I took it from an example in http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit16/papers/dev_int_204.pdf (page 21).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>App</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/esri/css/main.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/"></script>    
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/SceneView",
            "esri/layers/SceneLayer",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/core/scheduling",
            "esri/geometry/Point",

            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Map, SceneView, SceneLayer, FeatureLayer, scheduling, Point) {


            const countries = new FeatureLayer({
                url: "https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/World_Countries_(Generalized)/FeatureServer"
            });

            // Create Map
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray",
                layers: [countries]
            });

            // Create the SceneView
            const view = new SceneView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                center: [-74, 1],
                scale: 75000000
            });


            // Rotation function
            var scale = view.scale;
            var center = view.center.clone();

            scheduling.addFrameTask({
                update: function(ev) {
                    var pt = new Point({
                        x: center.longitude + ev.spendInTask / 1000 * 5,
                        y: center.latitude
                    });

                    view.goTo({
                        target: pt,
                        scale: scale
                    });
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```